# Strange behaviour with cascading includes (2 servers acts differently)

Tags: php, include, require, include-path

We reproduced a kind of error that occurs on one of our production servers. Here how it goes :

We have 3 PHP files

**test1.php :**

```
Test 1
<?php require_once('test2.php'); ?>
```

**test2.php :**

```
Test 2
<?php require_once('test3.php'); ?>
```

**test3.php**

```
Test 3
```

**include_path** is the same on both servers, and the dot is not included in it for other reasons :

php_value include_path /var/www/xxxxxx/php/ZendFramework/1.11.x/:/var/www/xxxxxx/php/

On our dev server everything is fine (outputs Test 1 Test 2 Test 3), online, when we upload files, the first time we load /test1.php, it is ok, the second call and so on we get :

> Test 1 Test 2
>
> Warning: require_once(test3.php) [function.require-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'test3.php'
>   (include_path='/var/www/xxxxxx/php/ZendFramework/1.11.x/:/var/www/xxxxxx/php/')
>   in on line 2

Are there any other things we should know about that affects the behaviour of including files in PHP, other than include_path? It's had for me to distinguish what can happen as I don't have access to servers config files for the moment. And why it works the very first time on production server and fails after ? I just can't explain what it could be.

**Edit :** We also get strange characters sometimes in the error message (and the change at each refresh):

> [...] No such file or directory in °µ4ª on line 4

Comment: It looks like you've verified that you're trying to set `include_path` the same way in both environments, but does `ini_get('include_path')` verify that they really are the same?

Comment: Yes we already validated that, and I have to mention that the files we try to include are not in the include path anyways, we want to include current website files which are in the same directory each other.

Comment: Now I see. The documented behavior is that after looking in the include path, php looks in the directory of the calling file and the working directory. And you're seeing deviation in this behavior, which is strange. Both servers are running the same PHP version?

Comment: Curiously, we found that APC was problematic. When I uploaded on the production server, execution worked the first time, and then "Fatal error" occured the remaining time, which made me think about some kind of caching issue. We updated APC to the most recent version and everything's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

What version control software are you using? We've had issues in the past with Perforce in which we integrate from dev to prod and the file doesn't get copied to all of the load balancers. It's tricky to troubleshoot the first time because it seems to be an inconsistent PHP error and depending on what production server you are checking, the file will most likely be there.

Comment: We are using Subversion, but we put the files online manually via FTP.